# Enemies all going to one spot in Godot

Tags: game-physics, game-engine, godot, gdscript

I have been trying to make a battle-royale like game where the enemies all target other enemies or players close to them and if there are none they go to random positions. However they are all going to relatively the same spot and i dont know why. Here is my code:

```
extends KinematicBody2D

onready var player = get_node("../Square_Player")
var Bullet = preload("res://Bullet.tscn")

var time : int = 0

var targets : Array = []
var target : Vector2
var posible_targets : Array = []
var num : int = 0

func _ready():
    for node in get_tree().get_nodes_in_group("targets"):
        if node != self:
            targets.append(node)

func spawn_bullet(target):
    var bullet = Bullet.instance()
    bullet.position = position
    bullet.rotation = rotation
    bullet.target = target
    bullet.p_name = self.name
    get_parent().add_child(bullet)

func _process(delta):

    # using if statement check for error
    if target == null:
        targets.shuffle()
        for t in targets:
            if (t.position - position).length() < 1000:
                posible_targets.append(t)
                num = rand_range(0, posible_targets.size())
                target = posible_targets[num].position
                #target = t.position
            else:
                target = Vector2(rand_range(0, 1000), rand_range(0, 1000))
    else:
        pass

    if target == Vector2(0, 0):
        target = Vector2(rand_range(0, 1000), rand_range(0, 1000))

    else:
        pass

    print(target)
    
    var direction = target - position
    var distance = direction.length()
    direction = direction.normalized()
    position += direction * 200 * delta

    # rotate the enemy to face the player
    var angle = direction.angle_to(Vector2(1, 0))
    rotation = -angle + 89.525

    time += 1

    # if the enemy is close enough to the player, kill the player
    if distance < 1000 and time > 75:
        spawn_bullet(target)
        time = 0

func die():
    # make it invisible
    set_process(false)
    set_visible(false)
    # remove it from the targets group
    if "targets" in get_groups():
        remove_from_group("targets")
    queue_free()
```

I have tried to change the random numbers that are generated and i have played with different ammounts of enemies to see if the physics has been broken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First and foremost, remember to call `randomize` to seed the default random number generator. You can do so in `_ready`:

```
func _ready():
    randomize()
    for node in get_tree().get_nodes_in_group("targets"):
        if node != self:
            targets.append(node)
```

The random numbers are reproducible, as long as you have the same seed. By calling `randomize` you make Godot pick a seed based on the current time. Which is what makes it different every time.

Using `randomize` will affect `shuffle`, `rand_range` and any other function that uses random without a `RandomNumberGenerator` instance (and if you had a `RandomNumberGenerator` you would call `randomize` on it).

---

Second, I find this odd:

```
        targets.shuffle()
        for t in targets:
            if (t.position - position).length() < 1000:
                posible_targets.append(t)
                num = rand_range(0, posible_targets.size())
                target = posible_targets[num].position
                #target = t.position
            else:
                target = Vector2(rand_range(0, 1000), rand_range(0, 1000))
```

So, for each target that satisfies `(t.position - position).length() < 1000`, you add it to `posible_targets` and then pick a target from `posible_targets` at random. So you picking a target at random each time you add a target to `posible_targets`.

You could pick once at the end of the loop. Or better yet, you could simply pick the first target that satisfies `(t.position - position).length() < 1000`, because the targets are already shuffled.

Like this:

```
        # if we don't find another target, this will be the value
        target = Vector2(rand_range(0, 1000), rand_range(0, 1000))

        targets.shuffle()
        for t in targets:
            if (t.position - position).length() < 1000:
                target = t.position
                break
```

*By the way, I don't see you clean `posible_targets`, you were always adding, never removing. But, as you can see, you don't need `posible_targets` anyway.*

---

I also want to comment on this:

```
    if "targets" in get_groups():
        remove_from_group("targets")
    queue_free()
```

You can check if the node is in a group using `is_in_group`. However, there is little point in removing it since you are releasing the node with `queue_free` anyway.

---

Which brings me to this:

```
    for node in get_tree().get_nodes_in_group("targets"):
        if node != self:
            targets.append(node)
```

First of all, know that each time you call `get_nodes_in_group`, you get a new array. So there is no problem if you modify it. Thus, you can remove `self` from it:

```
    targets = get_tree().get_nodes_in_group("targets")
    targets.erase(self)
```

But since the targets might being released (`queue_free`). That array would be obsolete.

Consider:

```
        # if we don't find another target, this will be the value
        target = Vector2(rand_range(0, 1000), rand_range(0, 1000))

        var targets := get_tree().get_nodes_in_group("targets")
        targets.shuffle()
        for t in targets:
            if t != self and (t.position - position).length() < 1000:
                target = t.position
                break
```

Alternatively, add a check to see if you are not trying to access a dead target:

```
        # if we don't find another target, this will be the value
        target = Vector2(rand_range(0, 1000), rand_range(0, 1000))

        targets.shuffle()
        for t in targets:
            if is_instance_valid(t) and (t.position - position).length() < 1000:
                target = t.position
                break
```

You might also be interested in removing said dead targets, but I'll leave that up to you.

---

Last but far from least, you have declared `target` like this:

```
var target : Vector2
```

Which means, this will never be `true`: `target == null`.

This will, however I won't recommend considering `Vector(0.0, 0.0)` an invalid target (how do you know there isn't a target there?):

```
if target == Vector2(0, 0):
        target = Vector2(rand_range(0, 1000), rand_range(0, 1000))
```

Instead, you might want to pick a target in `_ready`. Which also suggest to extract the code to pick a target to another function which you can call where you need it.

This also puts into question when do you want to pick a new target. Perhaps you want to keep a reference to the node you got from `get_tree().get_nodes_in_group("targets")` and pick a new target when that dies? That, I don't know, it is your game design.